# javascript - Add a query string to url

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble redirecting the user after submitting a form. The form serves to allow the user to filter out doctors based on location, rating, and specialty. Here is my code for the form and javascript function:

```
<form onsubmit="getDoctors()" id="searchForm">
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="specialty">Specialty:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="specialty">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <% specialtyList.forEach(function(specialtyValue){%>
              <option value="<%= specialtyValue %>"><%= specialtyValue %></option>
            <% }); %>
          </select>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="rating">Min. Rating:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="rating">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
          </select>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="location">Location:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="location">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <% locationList.forEach(function(locationValue){%>
              <option value="<%= locationValue %>"><%= locationValue %></option>
            <% }); %>
          </select>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Search">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>


function getDoctors() {
    var specialty = document.getElementById('speciality');
    var rating = document.getElementById('rating');
    var location = document.getElementById('location');

    window.location.href("/doctors?specialty=" + specialty.options[specialty.selectedIndex].text + "&rating=" + rating.options[rating.selectedIndex].text + "&location=" + location.options[location.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

However, when I submit the form, all it does to the URL is put an empty query string: `/doctors?`

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: use `urlencode` before pass to `href` , Refer this link https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-decode-url-string/

Comment: Why are you interfering with JS in the first place here, instead of just letting the form submit normally? Just specify the right method and action, then you should not need any JS to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe I originally had `action="/doctors", but I don't see how I am able to change the query parameters that way.

Comment: What exactly do you think you would need to change ...? I mean, you are sending the option text content for some reason, whereas a normal form submit would send their values ... but you have text and value the exact same for all of your options, that would not really matter either ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the submit button, two things happen:

1. Some JavaScript runs that tells the browser to navigate to a new URL
2. The form submits, causing the browser to navigate to a new URL

The form submission comes last, so it wins. The JavaScript is, in effect, useless.

There are two approaches you can take to solve this.

1. Prevent the form submission from occurring
2. Make the form submission construct the URL you want

Option 2 is the simple approach here.

1. Remove the JS entirely. It doesn't do anything useful.
2. Add `name` attributes to all of your form controls.
3. Set the attribute `action="/doctors" in the``

The form will now use the name and values to construct the query string you were putting together manually.

Comment: Thank you! I did Option 2 and it worked. I guess I assumed having the `id` attribute would work the same way as the `name` attribute, but that was a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting wrong id below for "specialty" in `getElementById`.

**Here is the corrected one:**

`var specialty = document.getElementById('specialty');`